# Как получить количество данных из разных таблиц?(inner join на 2 условия)

Tags: mysql

Имеются таблицы:

`users`

```
+------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type              | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int unsigned      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| date       | datetime          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| refererId  | int               | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

И таблица `actions`

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| userId     | int unsigned     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| refererId  | int unsigned     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| added      | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| amount     | int unsigned     | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| commission | int unsigned     | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| onHold     | tinyint unsigned | NO   |     | 1       |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Как мне получить сгруппированную по дате количество регистраций и действий?
Под каждое действие в таблице `actions` создаётся строка. Добавлял оба inner-а и в if-е у count пытался названия таблиц ставить, но всё равно не то, что надо.
Пытался сделать так, но выдаёт только действия в этот день:

```
SELECT COUNT(if(amount > 0,1,NULL)) 'actions', COUNT(if(DATE(added) = DATE(date) AND amount != 0,1,NULL)) 'registration',  DATE(added) AS added, SUM(amount) AS amount, SUM(commission) AS comission
FROM actions
INNER JOIN user ref ON ref.id = actions.refererId
#INNER JOIN user use ON use.id = actions.userId
where actions.refererId = 1 AND onHold = 1
group By DATE(actions.added)
```

Результат:

```
+-------+--------------+------------+--------+-----------+
| actions | registration | added      | amount | comission |
+---------+--------------+------------+--------+-----------+
|     3   |            0 | 2022-05-16 |    210 |        63 |
|     1   |            0 | 2022-04-28 |     15 |         2 |
+---------+--------------+------------+--------+-----------+
```

Пытался сделать так, но выдаёт только регистрации в этот день:

```
SELECT COUNT(if(amount > 0,1,NULL)) 'actions', COUNT(if(DATE(added) = DATE(date) AND amount != 0,1,NULL)) 'registration',  DATE(added) AS added, SUM(amount) AS amount, SUM(commission) AS comission
FROM actions
#INNER JOIN user ref ON ref.id = actions.refererId
INNER JOIN user use ON use.id = actions.userId
where actions.refererId = 1 AND onHold = 1
group By DATE(actions.added)
```

Результат:

```
+---------+--------------+------------+--------+-----------+
| actions | registration | added      | amount | comission |
+---------+--------------+------------+--------+-----------+
|      1  |            1 | 2022-04-28 |     15 |         2 |
+---------+--------------+------------+--------+-----------+
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
+---------+--------------+------------+--------+-----------+
| actions | registration | added      | amount | comission |
+---------+--------------+------------+--------+-----------+
|       3 |            0 | 2022-05-16 |    210 |        63 |
|       1 |            1 | 2022-04-28 |     15 |         2 |
+---------+--------------+------------+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: а вы сначала выберите все даты из обеих таблиц, а потом эти таблицы сгруппированные к этим датам и приджойньте

Comment: Раз у вас не все нужные записи участвуют в выборке то убирайте группировку и смотрите сначала что вообще выбирает запрос с требуемым join и потом смотрите записи которые не попали в выборку но должны были в ней быть что у них с userId. Очевидно, что там либо отсутствующий в users id, либо пользователь у которого refererId != 1 и запись не попадает под where

Comment: @teran Это как? Можете в ответ добавить?

Comment: @Mike возможно, но всё равно. Как сразу по 2-м inner-ам получить? Ведь если сразу 2 включить, тогда `date` в `count` будет не уникальным

Comment: Вы не показали исходные данные и не описали что вообще такое поля refererId и userId таблицы actions. Почему refrererId присутствует и в users и в actions. И не написали в разрезе каких date хотите получить результат, по одному полю или по другому.

Comment: Зачем вообще происходит сравнение даты из пользователя с датой действия ? Что означает такого сакрального эта дата из пользователя

Comment: так что добавьте в вопрос исходные данные для того результата, который ожидаете получить и напишите почему именно такой результат ожидается

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-sql/1035#1035)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за наводку в комментариях по поводу отсутствующего `userId`. Так и было. Также столбик `refererId` в таблице `actions` излишен. Данный запрос был верным, после исправления он сработал:

```
SELECT COUNT(if(amount > 0,1,NULL)) 'actions', COUNT(if(DATE(added) = DATE(date) AND amount = 0,1,NULL)) 'registration',  DATE(added) AS added, SUM(amount) AS amount, SUM(commission) AS comission
FROM actions
INNER JOIN user use ON use.id = actions.userId
where use.refererId = 1 AND onHold = 1
group By DATE(actions.added)
```